# Why is there no .l files in the gcc source release?

Tags: gcc, open-source, yacc, lex

There's `.y` files for yacc,but why is there no `.l` lexer files?

Answer (score 1):

gcc hand code their own lexers

Comment: Can you elaborate how to find where the terminal nodes in `.y` are defined?

Comment: I don't know I've never looked at the source code myself, I just know they don't use (f)lex. You could try searching for where they implement the lexing function that yacc searches for (int yylex() by default).